# How to Run a Custom CountDownTimer?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, countdowntimer

Currently I am working on a custom CountDownTimer that accepts user input into to EditText views and then counts down (in minutes and seconds) to 0. After it reaches 0, an AlertDialog/Notification should run. For some reason, however, I can't seem to get my activity to work. I've looked at several examples across different websites, and I can't seem to figure out the issue.

Here is the code I have for the activity (Java): http://pastebin.com/mbFaMRdM

And here is the XML: http://pastebin.com/X3yxKFPT

Also, is there a way to implement some sort of reverse Chronometer (as a visualization for the timer, like in the Timely Android app)? Rather than just showing text that updates as the seconds and minutes count down.

EDIT:

I am able to enter the activity from the main activity of my app. Although, when I enter values into the two EditText views (minutes in one EditText, and seconds in another), and then press the Start button, nothing happens. I believe that the problem is in this portion of my code:

```
public class setSelfTimeActivity extends MainActivity {
long mStartTime;
int mId;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.set_timer_activity);
}

public void createTimer() {
    Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_button);


    startButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
        final EditText intervalTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.timer_minutes);
        final EditText countDownTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.timer_seconds);
        int time = Integer.parseInt(intervalTxt.getText().toString()) * 1000;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        new CountDownTimer(time, 1000) {

         public void onTick(final long millisUntilFinished) {


                countDownTxt.setText("CountDown:" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
             }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            Intent i = new Intent(setSelfTimeActivity.this,
                    PopUpActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }.start();
```

Comment: You need to do some preliminary debugging so you can post the **most relevant** code here and see what is/isn't being called.

Comment: Much better, thank you! You can start by removing the `run/runOnUiThread` stuff because that method already runs on the UI `Thread`. And you seem to have redundant code with `countDownTxt.setText("CountDown:" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);`

Comment: @codeMagic OK. I've removed run/runOnUiThread and also now only have countDownTxt.setText("CountDown:" + millisUntilFinished / 1000); written once.

Comment: Same result or what? Did you leave the log statement in? If so, is that not showing? I would set some breakpoints in there and see what gets hit. It looks correct to me. Also, check the value of `time` when the button is clicked.

Comment: @codeMagic I left the log statement in (and nothing is showing up). I still have the same result as before

Comment: And the value of `time`?

Comment: @codeMagic When I enter the time in the EditText, I put 10 (and nothing happens at all). Also... I just noticed that I wrote **countDownTxt.setText** ...and that didn't seem right to me (because how could I setText on an EditText view? Seemed odd). So I quickly just tried it with a TextView and still didn't get any text to appear/update/count down.

Comment: ---Not sure if it's the problem but the constructor should take a `long` but you are passing an `int`--- Oh geez, I just realized you are never calling `createTimer();`. Add that to `onCreate()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are never calling the method that creates the `Listener` on your `Button` so clicking the `Button` does nothing because there is no event attached to it. Add the method call to `onCreate()` and that should fix the issue

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.set_timer_activity);

    // you forgot this guy here
    createTimer();
}
```

Originally, there was some `run/runOnUiThread` calls in `onTick()` but this isn't necessary as that method already runs on the `UI Thread`. All that did is add more points of potential problems and some overhead.

[CountDownTimer Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

**Off-topic:**

Your parsings should have some error-checking such as wrapping it in a `try/catch`

```
try {
    int time = Integer.parseInt(intervalTxt.getText().toString()) * 1000;
}
catch (Exception e) {
    // add a message to the user or do something else in case an invalid character was entered
}
```

You need to move your parsing into the `onClick` or it will try to parse the empty `EditText` contents

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    // move it in here
    int time = Integer.parseInt(intervalTxt.getText().toString()) * 1000;
    new CountDownTimer(time, 1000) {

     public void onTick(final long millisUntilFinished) {
```

Comment: Wow. I can't believe I forgot that one thing.

Comment: It happens...took me awhile to notice. Happy coding! :)

Comment: Edit: Wait, for some reason my application is crashing now. I tried to start the Activity, and Eclipse keeps asking me to open the debug perspective now (and I get a blank black screen when I try to start the setSelfTimerActivity)

Comment: Ah, yes that is because of that last part of my answer. It is trying to parse a number that isn't there. See my edited answer (the last part)

Comment: OK. That works, and I can now access the activity. Yet, there still an error. The activity crashes when I click the Start button (to start the timer)

Comment: I have no idea without knowing what the log says. Look at the log from the crash and try to determine what the problem would be.

Comment: Wait! No. It works!! There was something wrong with my Log so I just removed it. It works so far now (it can count down in seconds, but now I just have to figure out how to count down in minutes).